# Can I sort conditional data from Excel file using Jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

I am trying to sort my raw data.

I would like to filter specific data column, and to be more specific, it would be the columns labled as "01_ANGLE, 02_Angle ... and so on.

so the method that I took is just simply adding strings of "01+"_ANGLE" and I use for loop so that I can generate the string in range of "01" - "100"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUUpm.png)

After that I use read.excel function to only read the column that I made.

but unfortunately some of the excel file are missing some columns as "47_ANGLE" or whatever.
I want the code to only read the columns that matches with the string generated whcih is "01_ANGLE" to "100_ANGLE"

Can anybody help? Also, I would really appreciate if someone could suggest a better (shorter) codes.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.  **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Comment: Why not just read the entire spreadsheet, and only keep the columns you want? `df = df[[c for c in df.columns if c in num]]`

Answer (score 0):

Just read the entire spreadsheet, then keep only the columns you want.

You only need 1 `for` loop if you use an f-string and set the width to 2 and the fill character to `0`.

`df.columns` is an iterable that contains the dataframe's column names.

```py
import pandas as pd

filename = r"C:\Users\Todd Bonzalez\Desktop\Spreadsheet.xlsx"

# Read the entire spreadsheet
df = pd.read_excel(filename)

# Use a set comprehension and an f-string to make a list of column names
columns = {f"{i:02}_ANGLE" for i in range(1, 101)}

# Use a list comprehension to keep only the columns you want
# It is equivalent to:
# angle_columns = []
# for column in df.columns:
#     if column in columns:
#         angle_columns.append(column)
df = df[[column for column in df.columns if column in columns]]
```

See:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language
- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions